# Animate width of container when children expand

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a gallery using javascript/jquery where the full-sized images slide out from the right. I managed to get that functionality working, but I now face another problem: I need the gallery's parent block (#content) to expand when the full-sized image slides out to accommodate its width. Setting its CSS width to "auto" failed, so I tried a few different ways of doing it in Jquery. So far, no dice.

Here's the code I'm working with. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#back').hide();
        $('#full-wrap').hide();
        $('#thumb-wrap a').children().not('img').hide();//hide image captions

        $('#thumb-wrap a').click(function(){

            var $big = $(this).index(); //get 0-based index of the thumb that was just clicked

            $('#thumb-wrap').hide(); //hide the thumbnails
            $(this).children().not('img').clone().appendTo($('#gallery-wrap')).wrapAll('<article/>').show(); //Clone the image captions and wrap them in an article
            $('#back').fadeIn(500); //make the back button appear

            $('#full-wrap img').eq($big).siblings().hide(); //Hide all fullsized images that don't match the index of the clicked thumb
            $('#full-wrap img').eq($big).show().css({background: '#603'}); //reveal fullsized image that does match the index of the clicked thumbnail

            var moveIt = parseInt($("#thumb-wrap").outerWidth()); //Get the width of the right div
            $("#content").width($("#content").width() + moveIt);//Extend #content by an area equal to the size of the thumb-wrap
            $('#full-wrap').show().animate({ right: '+=' + moveIt + 'px'}, 'slow'); //slide out by a distance equal to the width of thumb-wrap.

        });

        $('#back').click(function(){
            $('article').remove();//remove the article div
            $('#thumb-wrap').fadeIn(500);//reveal the thumbnails
            $('#full-wrap').delay(300).animate({right: '0', opacity: 'toggle'}, 400);//hide the fullsize image div
            $(this).fadeOut(600);//hide the back button
        });

     });
```

Comment: You may also want to paste your html. Or put everything on jsFiddle.

Comment: The live example is up at this location: http://tinyurl.com/47n6tlq

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A "block" element is alway max width, so if the parent is already max width - what needs to expand?

Comment: The #content block has a defined starting width that needs to expand when a full-sized image slides out. As it is now, the image is "stuck" inside the #gallery-wrap div, which is set to be a percentage of #content; that's why I need #content to expand.

Comment: You are going to have to address the problem better it is not immediately apparent from looking at you link. Have a look at this fiddle example too - you might be able to animate margin so the parent recognizes the size if its children. http://jsfiddle.net/DHqhX/3/

Comment: I need #content to expand to a width equal to its current width PLUS the width of the image that's expanding out. Let's say #content's starting width is 400px; if the image expanding out is 300px, I need #content's width to become 700px. I'll try animating the margin and see what happens.

Comment: Animating the margin didn't change anything. I don't know Javascript or Jquery-- it's taken me two days to build this little snippet of code-- so I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I figured the problem had something to do with my setting a max and min width to the container in the CSS, but after staring at it for so long I couldn't think of how to change those settings and still achieve the effect I wanted. After some sleep-- and thanks to @Emmanuel's suggestion of animating the left position-- I came up with this solution:

```
var moveIt = parseInt($("#thumb-wrap").outerWidth()); //Get the width of the thumb-wrap div
$('#content').animate({'maxWidth': '+=' + moveIt + 'px', 'left': '6%'}, 'fast'); //expand max-width by a length equal to #thumb-wrap
```

And, to shrink it back again when #back is clicked:

```
$('#content').animate({'maxWidth': '360px', 'left' : '43%'}, 'slow');
```

This, together with some changes in the CSS, got me an expanding container div. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery parent() on the matched items and set it to the width and height of the image that is sliding out.

Comment: Won't this shrink the #content div, though? It's at a fixed width-- let's say, 300px. If the full sized image sliding out is 400px, I want #content to expand to 700px.

Comment: just do it in relation to the size 300px. Using simple math operators to subtract the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that this line isn't working

```
$("#content").width($("#content").width() + moveIt);
```

Might want to change css to `section#content { left:%20; }` or something a bit less than 43%?

Also I think your #full-wrap animation is missing some quotes. I had a look at jQuery docs, and they wrap their css values in quotes like this:

```
$('#full-wrap').show().animate({ "right" : "+=" + moveIt + "px"}, 'slow');
```

as well as the full-wrap rollback animation:

```
$('#full-wrap').delay(300).animate({"right": '0', opacity: 'toggle'}, 400);//hide the fullsize image div
```

Also make sure that moveIt does hold an integer value. Just after calculating var moveIt add `alert(moveIt);` and make sure it's what it should be.